# Assign values to registers and add and subtract them

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am completely lost with this.
I need to program that calculates the following expression, using registers: 
varA = (varA + varB) − (varC + varD), where varA, varB, etc., are variables.
Assign integer values to the EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers for the aforementioned variables. (Meaning, you may hardcode the inputs)

My Code:

```
; AddTwo.asm - adds two 32-bit integers.
; Chapter 3 example

.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data

varA  dword 5
varB  dword 3
varC  dword 4
varD  dword 1

.code
main proc
mov eax,varA
add    eax,varB

 mov    ecx,varC
 add    ecx,varD

 mov  ebx,varA
 sub  edx,varD

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: What is the output or error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov    eax,varA
add    eax,varB
mov    ecx,varC
add    ecx,varD
```

This all makes perfect sense, `eax = varA + varB. ecx = varC + varD`.

At this point, just

```
sub eax, ecx
```

to get `eax = (varA + varB) - (varC + varD)`.

I'm not sure what was intended with

```
mov  ebx,varA
sub  edx,varD
```

That sets `ebx = varA`, and then sets `edx = edx - varD`. edx wasn't defined before, so this is a random number. Or maybe edx was originally cleared to zero, in which case edx is now equal to -varD. I wouldn't count on it though.

Comment: Ah, I understand better now. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jinna If the answer was correct, please accept it :)

Comment: @zx485 Oh huh, yeah I updated my github username years ago. Thank you